# How to make possibly empty interface incompatible with string in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

It is possible in typescript somehow make possibly empty interface incompatible with string?

```
interface IA {
    foo?:number;
}

function bar(arg:IA) {
}

bar("should not compile");
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=interface%20IA%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3F%3Anumber%3B%0A%7D%0A%20%20%0Afunction%20bar(arg%3AIA)%20%7B%0A%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0Abar(%22should%20not%20compile%22)%3B)

Added later:

More complex example with possible workaround which is limiting in different way (you can extend only classes or interfaces):

```
interface IACommon {
    common?:number;
    f1?:string;
    f2?:any;
}

interface IAWithF1 extends IACommon {
    f1:string;
}

interface IAWithF2 extends IACommon {
    f2:any;
}

type IA = IAWithF1 | IAWithF2;

function bar(arg:IA) {
}

bar("does not compile but next definition also does not compile");

interface IAExtended extends IA {
    ext?: any;
}
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=interface%20IACommon%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20common%3F%3Anumber%3B%0A%09f1%3F%3Astring%3B%0A%09f2%3F%3Aany%3B%0A%7D%0A%20%0Ainterface%20IAWithF1%20extends%20IACommon%20%7B%0A%09f1%3Astring%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20IAWithF2%20extends%20IACommon%20%7B%0A%09f2%3Aany%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20IA%20%3D%20IAWithF1%20%7C%20IAWithF2%3B%0A%20%0Afunction%20bar(arg%3AIA)%20%7B%0A%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0Abar(%22does%20not%20compile%20but%20next%20definition%20also%20does%20not%20compile%22)%3B%0A%0Ainterface%20IAExtended%20extends%20IA%20%7B%0A%09ext%3F%3A%20any%3B%0A%7D%0A)

In this I found only workaround to extend `IAExtended` from `IACommon` but that makes `IAExtended` also not protected against this bug with passing string instead of object.

Comment: No. It follows from this PR https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3823 as far as I remember.

Comment: Can you convert your code to use `class` instead of `interface` as a workaround?

Comment: No it needs to be just object, but there are multiple members and only some combinations of members are allowed so possibly I can create union type ...

Comment: Yes, maybe. Please add more details if you want a useful answer for this question. Otherwise simple *no* is the correct answer ;)

Comment: Added workaround. I will accept "No" answer after one day :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your interface a dictionary type, by setting the type of the key:

```
interface IA {
    [key: string]: any;
    foo?:number;
}

function bar(arg:IA) {
}

bar("wont compile");
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IA%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%3B%0A%09foo%3F%3Anumber%3B%0A%7D%0A%20%20%0Afunction%20bar(arg%3AIA)%20%7B%0A%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0Abar(%22wont%20compile%22)%3B)

Comment: Interesting. Of course this does not help me at all because it allows huge amount of another bugs. But it answers my original question.

Answer (score 2):

New feature of TS 2.2 allows this nice solution of problem:

```
interface IACore {
    foo?: number;
}

type IA = IACore & object;

function bar(arg:IA) {
}

bar("does not compile in TS 2.2.");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a better answer here (in case anybody comes looking).  I had a similar situation, but I won't bother showing that.  Let's go back to your original case.  A found a solution with only a slight change.

My version generates an error (at least as of TS 2.1.4):

```
interface IA {
    foo: number | undefined;
}

function bar(arg:IA) {
}

bar("should not compile");
```

The only semantic difference I can see here is you actually have to always provide a value for `foo` in all object literals *e.g.*,

```
bar({}); // Error
bar({ foo: undefined }); // OK
bar({} as IA); // Also OK
```

You can find some discussion on this point [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7426#issuecomment-258932829).